# DNA - optical response and fluorescence

Tags: optics, education, biophysics, fluorescence

I am curious about the state of affairs with the DNA fluorescence. I know that there was some initiative in physics community in 1980's and 1990's, but [some authors](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-9155/51/7/002/meta) question even whether DNA molecules couple to photons directly, or coupling is happening through quazilocal excitations and/or electro-chemical reactions.

---

Also, is DNA naturally polarized. If no, can it become "ionized" in a way, similar to atoms, and, hence, polarized?

Answer (score 1):

There is fairly little interest in observing DNA itself. We're much more interested in its physical properties and its protein interactions, in which case we tag the protein.

Comment: What about the study of optical response to reveal mutations?

Comment: We use proteins which bind to mutations and tag them to find mutations in DNA.

Comment: How about this? https://www.bioopticsworld.com/articles/print/volume-8/issue-1/features/genetics-dna-sequencing-laser-fluorescence-powers-sequencing-advances.html